# How can I push back onto a vector an instance of a class in C++

Tags: c++11, vector

Bear with me please, this is my first time posting.  I have 3 classes. Class Suppliers has a set of Class Parent.  Class Parent has a vector of Class location and Class location has data memebers. Ex (this is pseudo code, not my actual code. I've only shown this for simplicity sake):

```
Class Suppliers{
set<Parent> setter;
};
Class Parent{
vector<location> loc;
};
```

`

The following is the a constructor of the location class I created.  I run into no problems until lines I hit the two lines with the iterators. I am trying to find a specific Parent and push back a new location onto the Parent 'loc' vector.  So I pass in the iterator I've found previously as a reference.  But as soon as I try to push back the new instance of my location class I get the following error.

data.cpp:139:33: error: passing 'const std::vector' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = location; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = location]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

The last line also gives an error that says I cannot alter a read-only object.  I'm confused as to why this would be a read only object.  I did some research and thought that I needed to add a copy constructor.  However, that caused more problems than it solved.  Any ideas?

```
location::location(set<Parent>::iterator &it, vector<string> v){ 


 sup_id = v[0];
 address1 = v[2];
 address2 = v[3];
 city = v[4];
 state = v[5];
 country = v[6];
 zip = v[7];
 ((*it).loc).push_back(*this);
 ((*it).num)++;



}
```

Comment: Beside @Daniel Frey's answer, you have really poor code design because you should not pass a pointer of your instance **during its own construction**.

Comment: @Alexandre Severino, would you suggest when I initialize the object and create a pointer to the object and push it back that way (outside of the constructor)?

Comment: Have you considered using a **factory pattern**? You can create a `static` method that calls the `private constructor` for it's own class and, when it is properly instantiated, add to a list. All within this static method.
More information on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363338/Factory-Pattern-in-Cplusplus

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a `set` is sorted. If you'd be allowed to change an element through the iterator, it would basically mean that you could potentially invalidate the iterator and therefore since C++11, the [`iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of a `set` is a *constant* bidirectional iterator and thereby has the same semantics as the set's `const_iterator`.

The solution, although slightly ugly, is to remove, modify and re-insert the element. There is a proposal to allow modification of the keys of associative containers, but I don't know if there is any progress in getting it standardized.

Comment: Thank you! After some more research today I came to a similar conclusion and implemented a map instead. The values in the map do not use a const iterator.